# The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port error Docker nginx

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I'm trying to access my server thru `http://localhost:8343/` but it always displays the error:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
>
> nginx/1.14.2

Here is my configuration for **docker-compose.yml**.

```
/*other configurations*/
services:

    pages:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./pages/Dockerfile
        container_name: proj_idcf_pages_1
        ports:
            - "8180:80"
            - "8343:443"
        environment:
            - TZ=Asia/Tokyo
            - LA_PROJECT_DIR=laravel
        depends_on:
            - php7
        volumes:
            - ../service/pages/:/var/www/
            - ./ssl_key/:/etc/nginx/ssl_key
        networks:
            - proj_default
/*other configurations*/
```

**pages/Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos:centos7
FROM nginx:1.14.2

COPY pages/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN sed -i -e "s/access_log .*;$/access_log  \/dev\/stdout;/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN sed -i -e "s/error_log .*;$/error_log  \/dev\/stderr debug;/g" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**pages/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8343$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 8343 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost:8180;
    error_log  /dev/stderr debug;
    access_log  /dev/stdout;
    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl_key/localhost.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl_key/localhost.key;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php7:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

        add_header my_string 'start';
        add_header $request_filename $request_filename;
        add_header my_document_root $document_root;
        add_header fastcgi_script_name $fastcgi_script_name;
        add_header my_fastcgi_path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        add_header my_string_2 ‘end’;
    }
/*other settings*/
```

can someone help me figure this out? I'm stuck on this for days now :(

Comment: In your `docker-compose.yaml` in the ports section you bind the 8343 port of your host to the 443 port of your container. The 443 port in your container is configured on `default.conf` to listen https traffic. So you have either to visit `http://localhost:8180` or `https://localhost:8343`

Comment: @zochamx Yes I have done that with my instinct :) And now I'm dealing with another problem. Apologies in replying and reading your comment late, I lost my connection every time I put my server up. Maybe you can put that as an answer so that I can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yaml` ->

```
ports:
   - "8180:80"  
   - "8343:443" <------ Here you bind the host port 8343 to container's port 443
```

and in the nginx conf file ->

```
server {
    listen 8343 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl; <------ you configured that port to listen https traffic
```

So you have either to visit http://localhost:8180 or https://localhost:8343

Answer (score 0):

Nginx configuration did not work for me.
I had unsecure registry configuration, protected by reverse proxy nginx, which added TLS encryption and basic authentication.

For me solution was to add "relativeurls: true" to http part of registry configuration */etc/docker/registry/config.yml*

```
...
http:
  addr: :5000
  relativeurls: true
  headers:
    X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
...
```